# Chart.js : straight lines and curves lines in the same graph

Tags: chart.js

Not able to get straight and curved lines in the same graph,made both the datasets  **bezierCurve:false** and ,**bezierCurve :true** for them but not getting it, here is the file:http://fiddle.jshell.net/2omjx9dn/44/

need these two graph lines of the two different graphs in a single graph:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/2omjx9dn/42/

any help would be great !!!!

Answer (score 0):

bezierCurve is a chart level (not a dataset level) option. So you need to override the chart to do this. The easiest way would be to plug in to the hasValue function (it gets called right before the dataset line is drawn)

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var options = this.options;
        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, index) {
            var originalHasValue = dataset.points[0].hasValue;
            dataset.points[0].hasValue = function () {
                // change option by dataset index here
                options.bezierCurve = (index === 0) ? true : false;
                return originalHasValue.apply(this, arguments)
            }
        })
    }
});
```

and then

```
...
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```